# Changing input to div and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some code to change input into div's

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnChange').click(function(){
        $('#products, #mrp, #discount').replaceWith(function(){
                return '<div id="'+this.id+'">'+this.value+"</div>";
        });
    });
});
```

What I want is to change them back on Second Click of the button from div to input with same id's and the same value.
Or you could say undo what I did on first click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnChange').click(function () {
        $('#products, #mrp, #discount').replaceWith(function () {
            if ($(this).is('input')) {
                return $('<div />', {
                    id: this.id,
                    //use text to prevent html injection
                    text: this.value
                });
            } else {
                return $('<input />', {
                    id: this.id,
                    value: this.innerHTML
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pe6SA/)

Comment: There is also a way of is() selector for pure jquery.

Comment: @C-link yes... I started without the `.toLowerCase()` then it was simple

Comment: Thanks I tried it but made the mistake with html injection. Your's is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.toggleClass()` for this.
For example, if you have this form:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" class="visible clickable" />
    <div id="myDiv" class="hidden clickable">Hello</div>
</form>
```

and `.visible` and `.hidden` definitions are:

```
.visible {
    display: inline;
}

.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

then your javascript should be:

```
$('.clickable').click(function() {
    $('#myForm .clickable').toggleClass('visible').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A4Lvu/

Answer (score 0):

You could store the existing elements and reload them like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var collection = {};
    $('#btnChange').click(function () {
        $('#products, #mrp,  #discount').each(function () {
            if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
                collection[this.id] = this;
                $(this).replaceWith('<div id="' + this.id + '">' + this.value + "</div>");
            } else {
                $(this).replaceWith(collection[this.id]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

A [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/YkS8z/).